# Mosquitto doesn't run after upgrade

Tags: lets-encrypt, mosquitto

Recent update from mosquitto 1.4.15 to mosquitto 2.0.15 on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine broke the config, preventing mosquitto from starting.

I am using letsentcrypt and the issue is related to the encryption, as mosquitto runs fine, if I remove any encryption.

This is the mosquitto.conf, which worked fine on mosquitto v1, but not anymore on v2:

```
per_listener_settings true
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

allow_anonymous false

## local access
listener 1883
#localhost
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

## SSL access
listener 8883
cafile /home/pi/ssl-cert-mosq/mosq-ca.crt
certfile /home/pi/ssl-cert-mosq/mosq-serv.crt
keyfile /home/pi/ssl-cert-mosq/mosq-serv.key
```

The most basic config for mosquitto v2, where it still runs:

```
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd
listener 1883
```

I have followed the mosquitto migration instructions, and added the `misc/letsencrypt/mosquitto-copy.sh` hook to `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/deploy/`. After running it, it does add a `server.key` and `server.pem` to `/etc/mosquitt/certs`

Errorcode when trying to start the mosquitto service:

```
Job for mosquitto.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mosquitto.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Result from systemctl status mosquitto:

```
mosquitto.service - Mosquitto MQTT Broker
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mosquitto.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-05-10 09:14:15 CEST; 1min 2s ago
     Docs: man:mosquitto.conf(5)
           man:mosquitto(8)
  Process: 3464 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 3463 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown mosquitto:mosquitto /run/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3462 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -m 740 -p /run/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3458 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown mosquitto:mosquitto /var/log/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3443 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -m 740 -p /var/log/mosquitto (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3464 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mai 10 09:14:15 clb-desktop systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Mai 10 09:14:15 clb-desktop systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Mai 10 09:14:15 clb-desktop systemd[1]: Stopped Mosquitto MQTT Broker.
Mai 10 09:14:15 clb-desktop systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mai 10 09:14:15 clb-desktop systemd[1]: mosquitto.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mai 10 09:14:15 clb-desktop systemd[1]: Failed to start Mosquitto MQTT Broker.
```

Why does the config have cafile, certfile, keyfile, but the new mosquitto_copy hook only copies over 2 files?
How do I change the mosquitto config file now?

**EDIT**:

Output from `/var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log`

```
1683702854: mosquitto version 2.0.15 starting
1683702854: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1683702854: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1683702854: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1683702854: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1683702854: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.
1683702854: Error: Unable to load CA certificates. Check cafile "/home/pi/ssl-cert-mosq/mosq-ca.crt".
1683702854: Error: Unable to load server certificate "/home/pi/ssl-cert-mosq/mosq-serv.crt". Check certfile.
1683702854: OpenSSL Error[0]: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory
1683702854: OpenSSL Error[1]: error:20074002:BIO routines:file_ctrl:system lib
1683702854: OpenSSL Error[2]: error:140DC002:SSL routines:use_certificate_chain_file:system lib
```

Permissions of the files under `/etc/mosquitto/certs` are set with the migration tool:

```
    CERTIFICATE_DIR=/etc/mosquitto/certs

    
# Set ownership to Mosquitto
        chown mosquitto: ${CERTIFICATE_DIR}/server.pem ${CERTIFICATE_DIR}/server.key
    
        # Ensure permissions are restrictive
        chmod 0600 ${CERTIFICATE_DIR}/server.pem ${CERTIFICATE_DIR}/server.key
```

Under `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d` is just a single README file.

Comment: What is in `/var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log`? Also what is the ownership and permissions on the certificate files copied to `/etc/mosquitto/certs`? And what files do you have in `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d`?

Comment: have updated the original post with an EDIT to answer your questions hardillb.

Comment: The logs saying it's trying to access files in `/home/pi/ssl-cert-mosq` not `/etc/mosquitto/certs`

Comment: My mistake. I tried following different tutorials. I simply don't understand what to put in the config file. I currently use: 'cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/cert.pem'
'certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.pem'
'keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key', which starts the mosquitto broker without error, but it won't allow me to connect via 8883 encrypted, only via 1883.

Comment: I would suggest starting again with this question, include just the mosquitto.conf you are using now and which files are copied to where by the migration script. Also if you are not using client side certs then you do not need `cafile` entry at all. You should also be using the `fullchain.pem` for the `certfile`

Comment: Yes, started from scratch and now SSL over 8883 is working.